# Is there a quick way to delete VPC and all its dependencies at once?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Embarrassingly, I have never deleted a VPC on GCP and today when I wanted to delete one, I realised it is not a one click or a single commandline affair. This `gcloud compute networks delete xxx` brings me to a loop to find all the dependencies manually.

I've searched for command line to list all the dependencies of a VPC but the closest I can find is `gcloud compute shared-vpc list-associated-resources`which doesn't help.

Is there an easier way to delete VPC and all its dependencies at once? Knowing how can I list all the dependencies of a VPC is fabulous too.

Comment: You can maybe find the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66220972/how-to-find-all-resources-that-exists-inside-a-gcp-subnet) to be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting a Shared VPC host project without following the processes described here will cause an outage for instances in all service projects attached to the host project.
In each service project attached to the Shared VPC host project, a Service Project Admin must remove all dependencies on the host project. Dependencies might include instances, instance groups, instance templates, and load balancer forwarding rules.

**To list all the dependencies of a VPC**,you can try this command:

**gcloud compute shared-vpc list-associated-resources PROJECT_ID** where PROJECT_ID is ID for the project to get associated resources for.

Once a Service Project Admin has identified the resources that will be affected by the deprovisioning process, those resources will need to be deleted:

1.Delete instances that use subnets in the host project.

2.Delete managed instance groups and unmanaged instance groups that use subnets
in the host project.
3.Delete instance templates whose definitions depend on the host project.

4.Delete internal forwarding rules for internal TCP/UDP load balancers that
reference a subnet in a Shared VPC network of the host project.

**To delete a VPC**, you can go for this command as you mentioned:

**gcloud compute networks delete network-name**